# Pratique et pragmatique

Tags: usage, synonymes, grec

Quelle est la différence entre (titre d'un cours) :

> Thermodynamique : Une approche pragmatique.
>
> Thermodynamique : Une approche pratique.

Je connais la signification de pragmatique qui vient du grec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux formes sont proches mais je conseillerais la première :

- *Une approche pratique* indique que l'on va donner des informations simples, directes et applicables sur le sujet.
- *Une approche pragmatique* indique que l'on ne va pas beaucoup s'intéresser aux théories sur le sujet et que l'on va faire preuve d'adaptabilité.

Les deux s'opposent à une *approche théorique*, mais différemment.

Dans le cas de l'approche *pragmatique*, on ignore la théorie. Seule l'observation des résultats réels de l'expérience compte. On est proche de l'empirisme.

Dans celui de *pratique*, on ne rejette pas (forcément) la théorie. On peut au contraire montrer quel intérêt la théorie peut avoir dans le réel, la mettre en application.

Comment: J'ai tendance à comprendre "approche pratique" comme "avancer par la pratique"... comme dans "apprentissage pratique", ou "mise en pratique". Bref le contraire, ou le complément, de théorique. Mais en soi je pense que dans la plupart des contextes employer l'un ou l'autre va avoir le même sens. Peut-être une question de registre ? Je dirais que "pratique" est plus commun que "pragmatique".

Comment: @LaurentS. Je pense qu'il y a une nuance. Réponse enrichie pour répondre à ton commentaire.

Answer (score 2):

Hormis les nuances de sens il reste que la dichotomie entre la théorie et la pratique semble beaucoup plus directement et anciennement associée à l'adjectif [*pratique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pratique/1) qu'elle ne l'est à l'adjectif [*pragmatique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pragmatique), par emprunt spécialisé en droit et réemprunté plus récemment de l'allemand etc. On peut jeter un coup d’œil à un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une%20approche%20pratique%2Cune%20approche%20pragmatique%2Cune%20approche%20th%C3%A9orique%2Cune%20approche%20abstraite%2Cune%20approche%20concr%C3%A8te%2Cune%20approche%20*_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20pratique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20pragmatique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20th%C3%A9orique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20abstraite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20concr%C3%A8te%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cune%20approche%20%2A_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20globale_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20nouvelle_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20diff%C3%A9rente_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20historique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20scientifique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20th%C3%A9orique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20sociologique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20pragmatique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20d%27_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20int%C3%A9gr%C3%A9e_ADJ%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20pratique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20pragmatique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20th%C3%A9orique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20abstraite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20approche%20concr%C3%A8te%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cune%20approche%20*_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20globale_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20nouvelle_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20diff%C3%A9rente_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20historique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20scientifique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20th%C3%A9orique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20sociologique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20pragmatique_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20d'_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bune%20approche%20int%C3%A9gr%C3%A9e_ADJ%3B%2Cc0) pour d'autres idées, dichotomies ou leur réconciliation pour ainsi dire (*intégrée*, *globale*).

Answer (score 1):

Je ne connais pas la différence en français :

> Peut-être **pratique** va mieux ici, parce que **pragmatique** est
>   utilisé dans un contexte politique, tout au moins c'est le cas en anglais je pense,
>   mais **pratique** est plus scientifique. Dans le présent contexte ils sont peut-être semblables, en français et en anglais ! Mais, peut-être pour le marketing, **une approche pragmatique** convient aussi, je ne sais pas !

Pardonnez-moi pour mon  français élémentaire !

[Par exemple : pragmatique](https://kfgo.com/news/articles/2019/feb/02/uks-may-says-to-seek-pragmatic-brexit-solution-in-brussels/)

[image: pragmatique]

[image: pratique]

Answer (score 1):

(TLFi) pratique A. 1. Qui concerne l'action, l'intervention de la volonté humaine sur le réel pour le transformer (**p.oppos. à spéculatif, théorique**). Morale, philosophie pratique; méthode pratique.

(TLFi) pragmatique B. 1. [**P. oppos. à théorique, spéculatif**]
a) Qui concerne les faits réels, l'action et le comportement que leur observation et leur étude enseignent.

En considérant les deux définitions côte à côte on voit que l'aspect pratique diffère en cela qu'il est axé sur le but de fournir un produit concret (transformer) à partir d'une chose connue (le réel); l'aspect pragmatique vise à connaitre la chose elle-même (concerne les faits) à partir d'une observation de sa nature, sans recourir à la théorie ou tout au moins sans recourir à une théorie trop avancée. Cela explique l'aspect d'opposition à la théorie dans les deux cas, bien que l'on voit que ce n'est pas au même niveau.

Sur la base d'une comparaison des définitions, en espérant qu'elle soit sans fautes, je ne peux que spéculer les explications suivantes en espérant qu'elles puissent être suggestives, mais je n'affirme rien.
Donc, une approche pratique à la thermodynamique pourrait consister à étudier des principes tels que ceux de la  réfrigération ; une approche pragmatique à la thermodynamique par exemple serait une approche dans laquelle on n'essaie pas de comprendre la thermodynamique sur la base de la mécanique des quanta (thermodynamique quantique) mais seulement sur la base de la physique statistique.